# WPF Application auto-run is not fast

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, authentication, autorun

My application a WPF c# application.

I create a task schedule to auto launch my application when user is logged on.

But when user is logged on, until my AP is success to show, it needs 10~15 seconds.

It is the same result to use an empty application.

Does anyone have similar experiences?

Comment: Does the same happen if you just add you app to the Startup programs?

Comment: the first wpf appilication "starts" the wpf framework. for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time.aspx

Comment: Yes, my `startup` apps take a similar amount of time to start.

Comment: I find some question point. It is depended by complier with x86 or x64. x86's AP in 64bit machine is faster than x64's AP.